# as an bank account holder, can I invalidate all plaid authentications I might have provided earlier?

Tags: plaid

I have linked my Chase account with a brokerage. I am certain that under the covers the two services used Plaid API to make the authentication.
Can I now invalidate this authentication? And may be all such authentications to my bank account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Chase account might have been connected using OAuth. If it was, you can use the Chase Security Center to revoke the OAuth token: https://www.chase.com/digital/data-sharing

If your Chase account was not connected via OAuth, or if you're not sure if it was connected via OAuth or not, you can create an account at https://my.plaid.com/ and manage your permissions there to revoke access.

Comment: This is great! I didn't know about my.plaid.com